# How to return all rows that have more than 2 unique values?

Tags: r

Right now I have a vector called `closest.labels` that has the following data in it:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[3,]    9    9    9    9    9    9    9    7    7     4
```

What I would like to do is return the row data as well as the index of that row where there are more than two unique values.  In the above example this would only be the third row.  So far I have been partially successful using `apply` and a function that I created.  See below:

```
colCountFx <- function(col){
    result <- subset(list(index=col,count=length(unique(col))),length(unique(col))>2)
    return(result)
}
apply(closest.labels,1, colCountFx)
```

My issue is that this returns what appears to be an empty row for the first two records as well.  Output:

```
[[1]]
named list()

[[2]]
named list()

[[3]]
[[3]]$index
 [1] 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 7 7 4

[[3]]$count
[1] 3
```

What would I need to change to have nothing returned for the rows that are currently returning `named list()`? Also, I am fairly new to R so if you think there is a better way to go at this I am open to that as well.

Comment: Do you have to have the output in a nested list, with each element containing `index` and `count` sub-elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a `list` you're going for, you can try something like this. Personally, though, I find nested lists somewhat cumbersome.

First, some data (I've added an extra row for clarity):

```
closest.labels <- structure(c(2, 0, 9, 8, 2, 0, 9, 8, 2, 0, 9, 8, 2, 0, 9, 8, 2, 
                              0, 9, 8, 2, 0, 9, 5, 2, 0, 7, 6, 2, 0, 7, 7, 2, 0, 
                              4, 8, 2, 0, 4, 9), .Dim = c(4L, 10L))
```

Next, a modified function:

```
colCountFx <- function(data) {
  temp = apply(data, 1, function(x) length(unique(x)))
  result = which(temp > 2)
  out = vector("list")
  for (i in 1:length(result)) {
    out[[i]] = list(index = data[result[i], ], count = temp[result[i]])
  }
  names(out) = paste("row", result, sep = "_")
  out
}
```

Let's test it:

```
colCountFx(closest.labels)
# $row_3
# $row_3$index
# [1] 9 9 9 9 9 9 7 7 4 4
# 
# $row_3$count
# [1] 3
# 
# 
# $row_4
# $row_4$index
# [1] 8 8 8 8 8 5 6 7 8 9
# 
# $row_4$count
# [1] 5
```

Comment: I'm not set on a nested list, what would be a better alternative in your opinion?

Answer (score 1):

You could trim off the empty lists by using another index. Say:

```
remaining <- apply(closest.labels,1, colCountFx)
remaining.ind <- sapply(remaining,length) != 0
remaining[remaining.ind]
```

Or, expanding on Patrick Li's answer:

```
ind <- apply(closest.labels, 1, function(x) length(unique(x)))
which(ind > 2) #indices of rows that have more than 2 unique values
closest.labels[which(ind > 2),] #rows that have at least one unique value
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the index with the `length` of `unique` items applied across rows.  `mat` will be used as the name for the matrix containing the items.

```
nUnique <- apply( mat, 1, function(x) length(unique(x)) )
ind <- which(nUnique > 2)
```

You can just select rows now based on that index.

```
mat[ind,]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> ind <- apply(x, 1, function(x) length(unique(x)))
> ind
[1] 1 1 3
```